# How to get one column names where another column is not-empty in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to learn google spreadsheet and encountered following problem:

I am working on a google spreadsheet and I was stuck how to extract the second state name from the string.

## MWE

```
  A                    
1 Company   City       Rejected
2 A         Dublin     Jan 1, 2021
3 B         Chicago    Jan 2, 2021
4 C         Atlanta
5 D         Seattle
```

Required answer:

```
Rejected companies = A,B
```

Since the Rejected column is not empty, the company names should be included and separated by comma.

Link to the google sheet (public shared file): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit?usp=sharing

I would truly appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a formula you can use: `=textjoin(", ",False,QUERY(A2:L,"select B where H is not null",0))`

This combines a list of all company that were rejected and sets comma as a delimiter for them`

**Here's an example screenshot**
[image: Example]

Comment: Will you try at shared spreadsheet? It does not work there. The spreadsheet is public, you can edit.

Comment: Just pasted the formula. Looks like your sheet was missing the Iterative Calculation so i basically just turned it on. If you're curious why that's needed you can find an article for that over here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Cchoose-how-often-formulas-calculate but in a nutshell you're allowing a bit more complex formulas to work